# What version of Visual Studio can I use to develop on an RDLC with a 2005 namespace?

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc

I have a handful of RDLCs that KWHotel uses which start with the namespace:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

but I cannot get Visual Studio 2013 or 2015 to open these files without offering to convert them. After conversion they will not work with KWHotel. Visual C++ 2005 and 2008 open the files as plain XML, with no other IDE functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use design mode on an RDLC with the 2005 namespace in Visual Studio 2008.